# Setup VPN in docker

Tags: networking, vpn, virtualization, docker

I am working on connecting docker containers together. I have explored the options provided in docker for networking. Now I want to create a VPN kind of setup to connect docker nodes and containers. Is there any way to establish a VPN.

Answer (score 2):

As of version 1.9 (Nov 2015), Docker Networking is available.

https://docs.docker.com/v1.10/engine/userguide/networking/

Briefly you create a network

```
sudo docker network create networkname
```

Now when you run a container you add it to the network

```
docker run -d --net=networkname --name containername imagename
```

Now the /etc/hosts files will contain the addresses of the containers. So from another container you can reference "containername" as a hostname.

Comment: This is probably the better solution, although it does require you to run etcd (or something like it) somewhere.  Depending on your setup, you could though just create a VPN container that other containers share their network with (e.g. `docker run --name=vpn vpn_container`, then `docker run --net=vpn other_container`). But I would use docker networking if I was you

Answer (score 1):

OpenVPN is the most common solution at the moment. [This blog post](http://blog.docker.com/2013/09/docker-joyent-openvpn-bliss/) should link you to everything you need to know, including 
[working code](https://github.com/jpetazzo/dockvpn)

If that's not exactly what you're looking for, you can always enable SSH access between your containers and setup a [simple VPN using SSH](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH_VPN)